# Find a DIV with a certain CSS style using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a bunch of DIV's that all have the same class and style except for 1.

```
    <div id="0" class="divpage" style="display:none"></div>
    <div id="1" class="divpage" style="display:none"></div>
    <div id="2" class="divpage" style="display:none"></div>
    <div id="3" class="divpage" style="display:none"></div>
    <div id="4" class="divpage" style="display:block"></div>
    <div id="5" class="divpage" style="display:none"></div>
    <div id="6" class="divpage" style="display:none"></div>
```

I need to find out the id of the div that is 'display:block'.  I used the following code but it only returns the first div's id.

```
var num = $(".divpage").attr("id");
```

How do I modify this to find the correct id?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

using `:visible` will find the div that is visible

You should not use numbers as id, i think its only valid in html5

```
var num = $('.divpage:visible').attr('id');
```

Comment: anyway consider using and toggling a .hidden class instead of using inline css

Comment: "In CSS2, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [A-Za-z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters 161 and higher, plus the hyphen (-); they cannot start with a hyphen or a digit." see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100048/css-style-not-recognizing-numbers

Answer (score 3):

Like this -

```
var theID = $('.divpage[style="display:block"]').attr('id');
```

Comment: This is the right answer to the question as posed, but I think he really wanted to ask the question answered by Anton :-)