# Why CSS class declaration isn't working on a tagged <div>?

Tags: css, class, html, declaration

I want to create a clean CSS coding where classes are created for specific attributes, e.g. ".20mleft" class for a 20px margin-left to html elements applied. I want a div to have a 620px width and the other div having 220px width. Both divs are floated left and the 620px width div should have a 20px margin on its right. Both divs are contained inside a container class div. These are the codes.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="8cols fleft 20mright" style="border:1px #333 solid;"><p>This is the Main Content</p></div>
  <div class="3cols fleft" style="border:1px #333 solid;"><p>This is theSidebar</p></div>
</div>
```

I am using a 12 column 960 grid BTW.

CSS:

```
/** FLOAT OPTIONS **/
.fleft{float:left;}

/** BOX ELEMENTS **/
.container{width:940px; margin:0 auto;}
...
.3cols {width: 220px;}
...
.8cols {width: 620px;}

/** MARGIN OPTIONS **/
...
.20mright{margin-right:20px;}
```

**Problem:** The properties of .fleft class is the ONLY ONE working at all. **The properties of the .8cols, .3cols and .20mright classes failed to apply.** I checked Firefox's Inspector and I couldn't see the properties, except the.fleft class declaration. It seems like the divs' widths are controlled by the contents inside it.

For better explanation, download the picture below:

[Sample Picture](https://www.mediafire.com/?8l8lo4ihd50e319)

P.S. Ignore the header above. This is my project in case you are wondering.

Please help me ASAP. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please make a Jfiddle

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS style not recognizing numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11100048/css-style-not-recognizing-numbers)

Answer (score 5):

CSS syntax requires class names *used as identifiers* to start with a letter, underscore, or dash.

You can, however, use escapes to get around this issue. For example, you can escape "8cols" as:

```
.\38 cols { width: 620px; }
```

in the CSS file. Personally that seems like something that'd get ugly pretty quick. [Here is a quote tool for CSS.](http://mothereff.in/css-escapes#--indent1)

It's not quite correct to say that special characters are "invalid" in class names and "id" values; they're not, but they have to be treated specially. The rules are for *identifiers*, but neither class names nor "id" values need to be identifiers.

Comment: Why does that necessitate a fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

CSS class names beginning with number character are invalid. Please read [What characters are valid in CSS class selectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors)

Answer (score 2):

[Here the best answer related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-selectors)

A **Class** name must begin with an underscore `(_)`, a dash `(-)`, or a `letter(a–z)`, and must be at least 2 chars length.

```
-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*
```